# VSTO Add-In: Detect check-in/check out of documents or ribbon UI changed event

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

I've got an Application Level VSTO Add-In for Office 2013/2016. I need to set the active document into Draft mode.
I'm using the `DocumentChange` and it works fine as long as documents are opened from Word.

When a document is opened from SharePoint from a library that has Checkin/Checkout enable, it first opens Word in a minimal view:

[image: Checkout Required view]

The `DocumentChange` fires, but as soon as the user clicks Check Out the document goes back into normal view mode.

So, I need to either hook up to a "Check Out" event, or to an event when the Ribbon visibility is being updated. I couldn't find either. Is there an event I can use?

Comment: I am not able to test this but 2 document event types come to mind: 'sync' (doubtful) and 'protected view'. The checkout itself happens on SharePoint but i assume the document is opened in protected view until the checkout button is clicked and succeeds. Upon success maybe there's a 'end protected view' event firing.

Comment: Full list of events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.application